# STM32F401RE PWM Mode doesn't work in Protues

Tags: timer, stm32, pwm, stm32f4, proteus

I'm trying to generate PWM wave but it seems that proteus has a problem with it. I've tried to do so using CMSIS and CubeMX and neither of them works.

tested timers: TIM 1, 2, 4, 5 with all their channels

[Timer configuration in CubeMX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAZfy.png)
[Proteus Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt4Vp.png)

Edited:
CubeMX doesn't generate HAL_TIM_PWM_Start as part of the generated codes for TIM's. adding HAL_TIM_PWM_Start to the code and changing the value of Pulse to a non-zero amount, fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set Pulse value greater than zero. It is the PWM's duty value.

Comment: I fixed that. But still, the problem didn't resolve.

Comment: Do you start PWM using 'HAL_TIM_PWM_Start' function? Can you please share your clock configuration?

Comment: I thought CubeMX write HAL_TIM_PWM_Start as part of the generated codes. It seems that was the problem. thank you for your help.